# How to print WCHAR [ ] into a file in linux

Tags: c++, linux, clr, clang++, coreclr

I am trying to profile .NET core application using IcorProfiler API(compiled using clang++) in linux.
Here I am trying to Print module name in to the file, that filled using GetModuleInfo2() in WCHAR wszName[300] variable.

```
    ModuleID moduleID;
    LPCBYTE pbBaseLoadAddr;
    WCHAR wszName[300];
    ULONG cchNameIn = _countof(wszName);
    ULONG cchNameOut;
    AssemblyID assemblyID;
    DWORD pdwModuleFlags = 0;

   GetModuleInfo2(moduleID, &pbBaseLoadAddr, cchNameIn, &cchNameOut, wszName, &assemblyID, &pdwModuleFlags);
```

Trial1:
After executing GetModuleInfo2() printing parameter values in to the file as follows.

```
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("/tmp/myfile.txt","a");
fwprintf (pFile, L"wszName: %ls \n",wszName);
fclose (pFile);
```

Printed output in file as follows.

```
wszName: ?????????????????????????????????????
wszName: ???????????????????????????????????l??
wszName: ??????????????????????????????????????????????????l????
```

Trial2:

```
wofstream of;
    char threadid[64];
    sprintf(threadid,"/tmp/module-%d.txt",getpid());
    of.open(threadid,std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
     of<< "After MODULENAME:" << wszName << "    " <<
         "cchNameIn:" << cchNameIn <<"  " <<
         "cchNameOut:"<< cchNameOut << " " <<"pbBaseLoadAddr:" << pbBaseLoadAddr << " " <<
         "pdwModuleFlags:" << pdwModuleFlags << " " << "assemblyID:" << assemblyID << std::endl;               
    of.close();
```

Printed output in file as follows.

Before MODULENAME:0x7ffe35f07010 cchNameIn:300  cchNameOut:2557930008 pbBaseLoadAddr:0x1 pdwModuleFlags:0 assemblyID:140525290184540

After MODULENAME:0x7ffe35f07010  cchNameIn:300  cchNameOut:80 pbBaseLoadAddr:0x7fce97e40000 pdwModuleFlags:1 assemblyID:31169008

writing WCHAR [ ] in to file using fwprintf()  is printing question marks and writing using wofstream Printing its address in Linux.

Is this correct approach to get the module name from IcorProfiler API ?If yes How can I print module name(wszname) in to the file?

Answer (score 0):

I would use 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/wcstombs (wcstombs_s) to first convert it into chars and then go with any way you would normally use to write the file

```
char name[300]; // Limitation was used from the question code
size_t convertedChars = 0;

if (wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, name, 300, wszName) != 0)
{
    // Error
}

if (convertedChars != cchNameOut)
{
    // Error
}
```

Edit:
After testing it out in Linux, it appears that WCHAR is actually a char16_t (unlike windows, where it's defined as a wchar_t).Nice read on the difference is here https://ducmanhphan.github.io/2018-12-06-How-to-use-char-wchar_t-char16_t-char32_t-right-a-way-in-C++/

The char16_t into a char array is a little tricky since you have to parse each character individually. You can use [std::c16rtomb](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/c16rtomb).